# CSS navigation list overlapping text

Tags: html, css, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a html and css document in visual studio 2015. When I request the CSS file from the html, it doesn't load correctly and overlaps a h1 and a p tag.

html:

```css
body{
    background-color: cyan;
    }
    ul.navbar {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 2em;
    left: 1em;
    width: 9em;
    }
    ul.navbar li {
    background: white;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding: 0.3em;
    border-right: 1em solid black 
    }
    ul.navbar a {
    text-decoration: none 
    }
    a:link {
    color: blue 
    }
    a:visited {
    color: blue 
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Empty</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="CSS/Style1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <ul class="navbar">
        <li><a href="Index.html">Index</a>
        <li><a href="Empty.html">Empty</a>
    </ul>
    <h1>Welcome to Alex's Website, this is not useful at all!</h1>
<p>Text text text, bla bla bla.</p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I don`t know what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`position: absolute;` removes the element from the document flow. So it will go over your elements because it is positioned **absolutely**, and not affected by your other elements.

Remove this:

```
position: absolute;
top: 2em;
left: 1em;
```

From your `ul.navbar` block.

Or, if you don't want to change exactly where the header is, you can add `padding-top: 100px;` to your `body` block, to push the rest of your content down, out of the way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the list overlapping h1 or p tag, I think its because you have the ul.navbar - position:absolute. Remove it and try something else.